# Active Directory - Difference between User-Cert and X509-Cert attributes

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I came across two user object attributes **User-Cert** (ldap name: *userCert*) and **X509-Cert** (ldap name: *userCertificate*) in Active Directory that sound similar, but doesn't seem so.

As per documentation (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-usercertificate), *X509-Cert* (*userCertificate*) holds the DER-encoded X.509v3 certificates and contains the public key certificates issued to the user by Microsoft Certificate Service. This can be then used for authentication purposes.

However, there is no clarity on what is *User-Cert* (*userCert*) attribute is and its uses. The documentation says *Nortel v1 or DMS certificates* - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-usercert.

Could somebody please shed some light on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user-cert` originally used to store certificates for S/MIME purposes (to lookup for recipient certificates). But it is replaced with `userCertificate` attribute. For example, MS Outlook reads `user-cert` attribute, but do not use it in any way (ignores its value completely).

Comment: Thanks @Crypt32. There is a separate `User-SMIME-Certificate` attribute as well, which also seem to be intended for S/MIME purposes. Isn't it?
Is `user-cert` kind of obsolete now, with no practical use?

Comment: `user-cert` is obsolete. In fact, there are enough obsolete attributes in Active Directory and replaced with other attributes. In LDAP you cannot remove (only disable, but yet not remove) attributes from classes, only add and by the time, the number of attributes (both, used and unused) only increases.